# Removing boilerplate from ASP.NET MVC actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have something like this in almost every action:

```
public ActionResult Show(int object_id)
{
    Object obj = ObjectRepository.ById(object_id);
    if (obj == null)
    {
        throw new HttpException(404);
    }
    if (obj.SomeCheck)
    {
        throw new HttpException(403);
    }
    // processing
}
```

Question is how to move object getting (and throwing http exceptions) away from action and have something like this:

```
public ActionResult Show(Object obj)
{
    // processing
}
```

UPD: Can't change ObjectRepository and model itself, it's used not only with ASP.NET but in other parts of the project.

Comment: Hmm...you might want to research ActionFilters....otherwise, is it possible to refactor the .ByID method to accept an nullable ?int instead of an int, and if null...to then throw the exceptions there?

Comment: @rnirnber - A repository shouldn't throw HttpExceptions so that would just shift the problem.

Comment: I'm installing the SP2 update to VS2013 right now so I can't look into it. I'm wondering if maybe there's a way to have a custom class derived from ActionResult that could be used in place of ActionResult?

Personally, I would probably refactor the .ByID method to take an optional Action delegate with the exception throwing. The Action could be invoked if there's no ID. You could theoretically define the Action as static readonly and move it somewhere high up like at a base controller to avoid the redundancy in the code

Comment: @awsum how to call the Show method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have suggested you could write filters or invoke an AOP framework like PostSharp.

However, that might be a tall order for some. You might want to consider writing something simple, maintainable and fairly readable, that everyone on the team can immediately understand:

```
public ActionResult Show(int object_id)
{
    SomeClass obj = Require<SomeClass>(object_id, assumption: o => o.SomeCheck);
    // processing
}

//Perhaps: put this in a base controller or other common class
private object Require<T>(int id, Func<object, bool> assumption) where T : class
{
    var o = ObjectRepository.ById(object_id) as T;  

    //Result is required
    if (o == null) {
        throw new HttpException(404);
    }

    //Verify assumption
    if (!assumption(o)) {
        throw new HttpException(403);
    }

    return o;
}
```

Comment: looks like an best solution for me. fits in our code base perfectly

Comment: While this is the best approach for removing boilerplate, it does rely on exceptions for application logic. If you are building the next StackOverflow, you would return specific action results instead.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to refactor your boilerplate into a private method:

```
private object GetItem(object obj) {
  Object obj = ObjectRepository.ById(object_id);

  if (obj == null) {
    throw new HttpException(404);
  }

  if (obj.SomeCheck()) {
    throw new HttpException(403);
  }

  return obj;
}
```

Then:

```
public ActionResult Show(int object_id) {
  object obj = GetItem(object_id);

  // processing
}
```

Comment: This solution will need a generic type parameter to have access to obj.SomeCheck().

Comment: @BrianR.Mullin, it is illustrative. Other possibilities are replacing `object` with a base class or interface, or typecasting when calling `SomeCheck()`.

Answer (score 2):

You might look at

- Writing a custom filter attribute such as an `AuthorizationAttribute` or `ValidateInputAttribute`. They can be applied to the entire controller or to specify methods (actions). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695917.aspx#id0070026 for an overview.
- You might want to look at using [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) (Aspect-Oriented Programming framework) to inject suitable aspects into your methods.

Answer (score 1):

Others have provided some good answers. Among them, I like the idea of using an action filter but unfortunately I don't believe it will work very well as you'll be forced to use property injection (or explicit instantiation - yuck!) for the repository, which I'd prefer to avoid. For this reason, I think a dedicated controller method is a better option.

I will throw one more idea in the hat, though.

You mentioned that you can't change `ObjectRepository` but you can always abstract it:

```
public class HttpObjectService /*: IObjectService */
{
    private readonly /*I*/ObjectRepository _repository;

    public HttpObjectService(/*I*/ObjectRepository repository)
    {
        if (repository == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public Object ById(int id)
    {
        var obj = _repository.ById(id);
        /* Check and throw HttpExceptions */
    }
}
```

Then inject this into your controller. Whether or not you like the idea of a "web-specific" service that throws `HttpExceptions`directly is a matter of taste but it is extremely reusable and, in this case, I believe it provides a cleaner separation of concerns than private validation methods in the controller.

The downside, of course, is that you're allowing your controller to delegate its responses (in the event of an error) directly to a third party. You may prefer your controller to have absolute control over this - that would be a reasonable criticism. In that case, you could always pass an `ObjectValidator` object into the constructor from the controller, which takes care of the validation. This would let your controller maintain control of what exceptions are thrown regardless of the service implementation.

You would have to be considerate of where this fits into your project architecture - it would probably belong in a separate assembly to your MVC project but one that is dedicated to web-based UIs.